# Angular Material MatChipList MatError not visible when setting errorstate without focus

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I had some trouble displaying a mat-error on a chiplist. According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11260) the `errorState` should be set explicitly to show the mat-error.

This solution works fine, but only when the chiplist has focus. It does not work when the chiplist is not focussed. See [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matchiplist-with-error-message-z5fsfe?file=app%2Fchips-input-example.ts). In my case, the list of valid fruits changes later on due to some API call when the chiplist has no focus.

How can I show the mat-error when the chiplist has no focus?

Comment: Can you update your stackblitz link to provide the editor url and not the application url?

Comment: @Marshal that was stupid of me. I updated the link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the `errorState` appears to be working without focus, indicated by the placeholder and underline turning `red`.

I suspect you need the `mat-error` to display as well however, you are missing your `*ngIf`.

`<mat-error *ngIf="chipList.errorState">Too many chips</mat-error>`

*STACKBLITZ*

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matchiplist-with-error-message-tsdxfa?file=app/chips-input-example.html

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't work without the ngif?

Answer (score -2):

You should add the validator in  and prevent invalid item adding as follows.
For exampl:

Component:

```
export class ExampleComponent {
    items = [];
    emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.email]);

    addItem(event) {
        if (this.emailFormControl.valid) {
            items.push(event.value)
        }
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Template:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-chip-list [formControl]="emailFormControl">
        .
        .
        .
    </mat-chip-list>
</mat-form-field>
```